# How can I "reset" aptitude?

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, aptitude

I've inherited an Ubuntu 12.04 server where package management is *completely* messed up. Any aptitude command fails with errors like this one (for every installed package, as far as I can tell):

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-common:
 grub-common depends on libdevmapper1.02.1 (>= 2:1.02.36); however:
  Package libdevmapper1.02.1 is not configured yet.
```

There are dozens of unresolved dependencies, and trying to resolve them leads to further unresolved dependencies. In addition, there are dozens of other errors I can't even find anywhere (and won't describe). I can't spend more hours trying to fix this.

Is there any possible way to "reset" aptitude and start with a clean slate, without actually removing currently installed and configured packages?

Comment: At this point, you should just reinstall.

Comment: What happens when you try to configure the package(s) it says are not configured yet?

Comment: `aptitude install` perhaps, (with no further arguments) so as to give the packaging system an opportunity to complete the outstanding installation tasks.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist: just more strange configuration issues. Already tried `aptitude install`. I suppose reinstall is the best option here.

Comment: I could not install VLC on Ubuntu 16.04 with aptitude without removing Unity and 300 packages according to aptitude. `apt-get remove aptitude` followed by an install did not help. As a workaround I used apt-get to install VLC which worked. Aptitude really needs a reset command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running:

```
 # dpkg --configure --pending
 # dpkg --configure -a
 # apt-get -f install
```

If that doesn't help, and you are unable to resolve further conflicts/problems on your own or get someone whos more experienced with dpkg at the helm, or just backup /etc and reinstall.

Comment: None of that resolves the configuration/dependency nightmare. I guess backup and reinstall is the way to go here.

Answer (score 9):

If you find aptitude state completely messed up, you can try (as root):

```
# rm -f /var/lib/aptitude/pkgstates*
```

And then restart it.  That should clear aptitude's idea of what needs to be (re)installed/upgraded and then you can Update from there.

This happens to me periodically if I change the sources list or alter the release Pins in preferences and it gets into a package resolution disaster (or runs forever trying to find an upgrade path).

Comment: Still useful for Ubuntu 21.10, after checking with `apt-get` and `dpkg` that my system was not broken.

Comment: If removing `pkgstates` helps you, it would indicate to me that you're regularly managing packages with `apt`, `apt-get` or any of the UI package managers instead of `aptitude`. Going `aptitude` **all the way** should hardly ever display such issues and if it does, it'll only be for a small number of packages that have been installed/uninstalled outside of Aptitude. And that's kinda expected with Aptitude's separate state-keeping. If you're not using Aptitude's TUI, there's no good reason to use Aptitude at all. And if you're using Aptitude's TUI, you should try to avoid `apt` / `apt-get`.

Comment: I would expect a huge problematic `aptitude` state after upgrading your system with any tool that's not Aptitude. So if you like Aptitude, I suggest to always upgrade your system with `aptitude` and to **not let** the GUI tools or `do-release-upgrade` do it.

Comment: Interesting @blubberdiblub, `do-release-upgrade` did not break things, but the initial issue arose lately, i.e. with Xubuntu 23.10. Not sure what was the trigger though.